# how force python3.6 use new fresh install of openssl I installed new version of openSSL 1.1.1 on ubuntu, python2 does load it, but python3 doesn't

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, python-3.6, ubuntu-14.04

$python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 13 2018, 12:45:42)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend; print(backend.openssl_version_text())
> > >       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
> > >         utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
> > >       OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
> > >       [11:14 PM] $ python3.6
> > >       Python 3.6.4 (default, Apr 21 2020, 19:02:28)
> > >       [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
> > >       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> > >
> > > from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend; print(backend.openssl_version_text())
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/**init**.py", line 7, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 75, in 
> > >           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 205, in 
> > >           _verify_openssl_version(Binding.lib)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 169, in _verify_openssl_version
> > >           "You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.1, which is no longer "
> > >       RuntimeError: You are linking against OpenSSL 1.0.1, which is no longer supported by the OpenSSL project. You need to upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSL.

Comment: Hi, could you try running `ldconfig` again to redo all the symlinks? Then try running that python program

Comment: Also, please try reinstalling the cryptography package with `--no-cache-dir` option (and avoid doing global install with `sudo pip`, also remove `-H` option if you used it).